# SPO: Trigger Workflow on Save/Upload of File?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document-library

Is there a way to configure a workflow to start when a user wants to publish a major file version to a specified Document Library?

Example of what I'm looking to do:

1. User clicks to publish a major version
2. Approval workflow starts (sent to User A & B, once they approve, send to User C for approval).

   - Users A, B, and C would be the same users for each document in that library.
3. Resolve Approval workflow

Comment: By accessing the approval status column in workflow, you can play with your requirement. hope this link helps you......https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa6b4653-bfd4-40dc-9fa0-39d1b0b8c298/how-to-conditionally-start-a-workflow-when-publishing-a-major-version-in-a-document-library-based-on?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default Approval workflow.

And start this workflow to approve publishing a major version of an item.

[image]

Note: This option is available only if support for major and minor versioning is enabled and content approval is turned on for the library.

[image]